# boost::asio client-server in different networks

Tags: sockets, boost, tcp

I have a client-server based project implemented with boost::asio. It works fine if client and server are running in the same network, let say server ip=192.168.2.20 and client ip=192.168.2.100. But if I change the ip address of the server to 192.168.3.20 the connection is not astablished, I get socket timeout. At the same time I'm able to ping 192.168.2.20 from the server's host( I mean from 192.168.3.x network ) and I'm able to do it vica versa.

What could be a problem here?

Comment: Should have something to do with firewall rules between two networks. Ping and TCP trafic can be (and often are) handled differently.

Comment: To narrow down the problem I did the following setup: PC1 with 2 interfaces 192.168.3.x and 192.168.2x where the client is running and the server is running on 192.168.2.x network. Pinging is fine but connect is still failed. What should be checked at first ?